# c# to json not rendering properly in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Hi Im trying to send a string to a view that looks like json.

Im sending a list of places:

```
class Place 
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public double latitude { get; set; }
            public double longitude { get; set; }
        }

List<Place> placeList = new List<Place>(); 
//add places to PlaceList

//Then i do this
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(placeList);
            ViewBag.Places = sJSON;
```

In the view its rendering output like this though:

```
[{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;sdf sdfsd sdf sd f&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;sdf sdf sd fsd sd sdf sdf dssd sdf sd s&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:53.740259851464685,&quot;longitude&quot;:-2.4602634343627927},
```

How do i get it to render as normal json in the view? minus `&quot;`etc?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your comment below you say your view is using `@ViewBag.Places`

Are you using Razor? If so the `@` syntax does the same thing as `<%:` - it encodes the content.

Use the `IHtmlString` interface to avoid it, so either:

```
ViewBag.Places = new HtmlString(sJSON);
```

Or

```
@HtmlString(ViewBag.Places)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Places)
```

also works

Answer (score 1):

did you try ?

```
string sJSON = HttpServerUtility.HmltDecode(oSerializer.Serialize(placeList));
```

Comment: also I think that it is strange that oSerializer.Serialize return html encoded string. As you sure that the rendering in your view doesn't have any pre-treatment ?

Comment: I tried: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(oSerializer.Serialize(placeList)); - same result

Comment: in my view i have: "places": @ViewBag.Places

Comment: so did you try <%= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.Places) %> ? (I don't use razor)