# Json Serialization Error in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization

Its asp.net mvc paradigm. I have a Prices property on model that is an `IList` of type `VMPrice`. In view I do something like

```
<%var serializer = System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();%>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var prices = '<%:serializer.Serialize(Model.Prices)%>';
  alert(prices);
  prices = $.parseJSON(prices);  // This line throws exception Invalid Json object
</script>
```

The alert call on fourth line shows following string

```
[{&quot;SKUID&quot;:3,&quot;ExFactoryPrice&quot;:765.00},{&quot;SKUID&quot;:5,&quot;ExFactoryPrice&quot;:39.91}]
```

What's the problem here and how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `"<%=%>"` instead of `<%: %>` so that it does not `html encode it`

also see this SO answer [c# to json not rendering properly in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605449/c-to-json-not-rendering-properly-in-view/4605488#4605488)

Answer (score 0):

You need to unescape the string before parsing it.

```
[{&quot;SKUID&quot;:3,&quot;ExFactoryPrice&quot;:765.00},{&quot;SKUID&quot;:5,&quot;ExFactoryPrice&quot;:39.91}]
```

Should be:

```
[{"SKUID":3,"ExFactoryPrice":765.00},{"SKUID":5,"ExFactoryPrice":39.91}]
```

The simple thing in this case would be to replace `&quote;` with `"`